# Shift All cells in a row between certain ranges 1 cell to right (and left)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have the beginning of a macro here to shift a collection of cells either one to the right or left, based on a macro button on that row. I'll need to copy the macro button for 500 cells in a column so the application.caller part is necessary.

```
Sub ShiftTheRow()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim rngMove As Range
    Dim rngAnchor As Range


    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

    Set rngAnchor = sh.TopLeftCell

    'Find numerical cells
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngMove = rngAnchor.Columns("X:DC").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rngMove Is Nothing Then
        'No numbers found
        Exit Sub
    Else
        rngMove.Cells(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftToRight
    End If


End Sub
```

Unfortunately (as you would expect) it moves the entire row one to the right, when I need the shifting of cells to be constrained between columns AO:DC.

(e.g I want all cells between A:AN for that row to remain unaffected, and all those from DE:onward to be unaffected also)

However I simply cannot figure out how to do this.

I have tried...
Set rngMove = rngAnchor.Columns("AO:DC").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)

But for some strange reason it will begin shifting cells at BB and go beyond DC.

Really at a loss here!

Comment: **1)** - You do not need 500 buttons and `Application.Caller`. You can simply click on the row and run the macro and use the row of the `ActiveCell`. **2)** - It's impossible to shift cells to the right using insert  **without** affecting the other cells on the right. If you shift `AO:DC` one to the right it will surely effect `DD: and beyond`. Use `Cut` and `Paste` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small function that will shift cells left or right without affecting other cells outside the desired range:

```
Sub shiftLeftRight(shiftRange As Range, leftRight As Integer)
'=== Note: pass leftRight as 1 or -1

    shiftRange.Cut
    shiftRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(, leftRight).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

I will leave how you determine and pass the range up to you, but I know there's a  better solution than 500 separate buttons.